# How to use lapply when substracting sublist and use str_extract function

Tags: r, lapply, stringr

I want extract years from the text.

The following code gives me a vector with the values of 1998 and 2009

```
description= "I was teaching at the univeristy from 1998 to 2009"
teaching = as.numeric(str_extract_all(description ,"\\d{4}")[[1]])
```

Then I want to subtract years

```
teaching[2] - teaching[1] 
[1] 11
```

But the problem is that I have a column in a dataframe with those texts and I want extract years from every text and subtract them.

I tried to do this but got confused

```
аа = lapply(df$description, str_extract_all,"\\d{4}")
bb = lapply(aa, function(x) x[1])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could try this:

```
# example data

df <- data.frame(description = paste("I was teaching at the univeristy from",1990:1995, "to",seq(2010,2020,by =2)))

#  description
#1 I was teaching at the univeristy from 1990 to 2010
#2 I was teaching at the univeristy from 1991 to 2012
#3 I was teaching at the univeristy from 1992 to 2014
#4 I was teaching at the univeristy from 1993 to 2016
#5 I was teaching at the univeristy from 1994 to 2018
#6 I was teaching at the univeristy from 1995 to 2020

years <- str_extract_all(df$description, "\\d{4}")
sapply(years, function(x) diff(as.numeric(x)))
# 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Alternative approach to deal with NAs:

```
# example data 
df <- data.frame(description = c(paste("I was teaching at the univeristy from",1990:1995, "to",seq(2010,2020,by =2)), "I was not teaching at all"))

years <- str_extract_all(df$description, "\\d{4}", simplify = TRUE)
apply(years, 1, function(x) diff(as.numeric(x)))
# 20 21 22 23 24 25 NA
```

Comment: thank you! It worked perfectly. How can I keep NA if a row doesn't have a pattern?

Comment: Glad it helped! I have edited the answer with a second approach that keeps the NA info

Comment: Thanks. I haven't know about "simplify" in str_extract function